# How do I transfer a variable out of a for loop?

Tags: c++

I am currently attempting to extract the sign bits, mantissa bits and exponent bits from a half precision floating point value. The particular piece of code I am using to carry out this process involves storing the floating point value into a bool array called `binary`.

I have attempted to extract out the necessary bit range for the respective fields by creating for loops. However, I still seem to be having issues with how the values are being stored. I have tried 2 different methods, one using `sprintf` and one using `snprintf`.

The problem still lies in the fact that the values stored in `mant` are getting overwritten for each iteration in the loop. I am unsure of how am I able to get the variable into another `char` array outside of the for loop.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    char mant [10];



    float num = 2.25; // number you want to convert into binary
    bool binary[16]; //create the binary array to store the 16 bit FP value
    floatingPointNumberToBinary(binary, num); //function to convert FP to binary
    printBinary(binary); // this function will display binary on console in 16 bit FP

    //For loop to extract mantissa bits
    for (int i=6; i < 16; i++)
    {
        //Method 1
        snprintf(mant, sizeof(mant), "%d", binary[i]); 

                //Method 2
        //n = sprintf(mant, "%d", binary[i]);
        //printf("%s", mant);
    }   
    printf("\n %s", mant);
    return 0;
}
```

The floating point value found in the binary array would be `0100000010000000`

The output of both methods provide the correct representation for the mantissa bit `0010000000`. 
As mentioned above, the issue lies with the fact that each bit is printed per each iteration of the loop. Since there was no line break being inputted, it looks as though it is printed in its whole.

If a line break was ended in the code such as

```cpp
//Method 2
        n = sprintf(mant, "%d", binary[i]);
        printf("\n%s\n", mant);
```

The bits would be spread out.

Comment: `"%d"` requires 32 or 64 bit on the stack, `binary[i]` is 8 bit only.

Comment: Consider using `std::bitset` instead of bool array - it offers `to_string` methods, which you can simply `substr()` later.

Comment: @S.M. -- `"%d"` requires a value of type `int`. Passing a value whose type is smaller than `int` to a varargs function (here, `snprintf`) promotes the value to `int` (or `unsigned int` in some cases). Regardless of whether `int` is 16, 32, 64, or whatever bits, the code is correct.

Comment: @PeteBecker Never heard about it. I know that int size will be placed on the stack, but I'm not sure, that other 3 or 7 bytes will be zeros.

Comment: @S.M. -- the smaller value is **promoted** to `int`. Promotions preserve value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare "std::string mant;" before the loop. Inside the loop, add "mant += std::to_string(binary[i]);". Then print mant after the loop ("printf("\n%s\n", mant.c_str());").

You can do it the hard, C way by advancing the pointer each iteration: "snprintf(mant + (i - 6), sizeof(mant) - (i - 6), "%d", binary[i]);".

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That is exactly what I needed